# NestJs provider isn't injected and says this.iGalleryRepository.addImage is not a function

Tags: mysql, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, clean-architecture

I am trying to make a nestjs typescript backend application which uses mysql as database using [clean architecture](https://www.educative.io/blog/clean-architecture-tutorial). I implemented JWT and Authorization but it doesn't see my function and i think the problem is with the dependency injection therefore i will share related files but if you need to see other files just let me know. I've been trying to solve this for 3-4 days. :/

Full Error :

> ERROR Method: POST; Path: /images/add; Error: this.iGalleryRepository.addImage is not a function

---

> My "AppModule" is named .RootModule (where i pack my app):

```js
    @Module({
      imports: [
          InfraModule,
          AuthModule,
          UserModule,
          ImageModule
      ]
    })
    export class RootModule { }
```

> Image Module:

```js
const persistenceProviders: Provider[] = [
    {
        provide: DITokens.ImageDITokens.ImageRepository,
        useFactory: (dataSource: DataSource) => dataSource.getRepository(TypeOrmImage).extend(TypeOrmImageRepositoryAdapter),
        inject: [DITokens.CoreDITokens.DataSource]

    }
];

@Module({
    controllers: [
        ImageController
    ],
    providers: [
        ...persistenceProviders,
        ImageService,
        ImageHandler
    ]
})
export class ImageModule { }
```

> You may ask where & how i define db (idk why ‍♂️) :

```js
export const databaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: DITokens.CoreDITokens.DataSource,
        useFactory: async () => {
            return AppDataSource.initialize();
        }
    }
];

.
.
.
@Global()
@Module({
    imports: [
        CqrsModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        ...providers,
        ...databaseProviders
    ],
    exports: [
        DITokens.CoreDITokens.CommandBus,
        DITokens.CoreDITokens.QueryBus,
        DITokens.CoreDITokens.EventBus,
        ...databaseProviders
    ]
})
export class InfraModule implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
    onApplicationBootstrap(): void {
        initializeTransactionalContext();
    }
}
```

> Image Controller :

I should mention that Logger.log(adapter, "CreateImageDTO"); works, i can see the output but can't see the line Logger.log(createdImage, "createdImage")

```js
@Controller('images')
@ApiTags('images')
export class ImageController {

    constructor(
        private readonly imageService: ImageService,
        private readonly imageHandler: ImageHandler,
    ) { }

@Post("add")
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiBody({ type: HttpRestApiModelCreateImageBody })
    @ApiResponse({ status: HttpStatus.OK, type: HttpRestApiResponseImage })
    public async createImage(
        @Body() body: HttpRestApiModelCreateImageBody

    ): Promise<CoreApiResponse<ImageUseCaseDTO>> {

        const adapter: ICreateImageDTO = await CreateImageDTO.new({
            parentId: body.parentId,
            title: body.title,
            imageUrl: body.imageUrl,
            type: body.type
        });

        Logger.log(adapter, "CreateImageDTO")

        const createdImage: ImageUseCaseDTO = await this.imageService.createImage(adapter);

        Logger.log(createdImage, "createdImage")

        return CoreApiResponse.success(createdImage);
    }
 }
```

> Image Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {

    /**
     * @param {IGalleryRepository} iGalleryRepository
     */
    constructor(
        @Inject(DITokens.ImageDITokens.ImageRepository)
        private readonly iGalleryRepository: IGalleryRepository
    ) { }
   
    public async createImage(payload: ICreateImageDTO): Promise<ImageUseCaseDTO> {
        const image: Image = await Image.new({
            title: payload.title,
            type: payload.type,
            parentId: payload.parentId,
            imageUrl: payload.imageUrl
        })

        await this.iGalleryRepository.addImage(image);

        return ImageUseCaseDTO.newFromImage(image);
    }

}
```

the line throws error is in the above snippet fyi

When i try to log this.iGalleryRepository using console.log() it gives the following:

```bash
Repository {
  target: [class TypeOrmImage],
  manager: <ref *1> EntityManager {
    '@instanceof': Symbol(EntityManager),
    repositories: [ [Repository], [Repository] ],
    treeRepositories: [],
    plainObjectToEntityTransformer: PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer {},
    connection: DataSource {
      '@instanceof': Symbol(DataSource),
      migrations: [],
      subscribers: [],
      entityMetadatas: [Array],
      name: 'default',
      options: [Object],
      logger: [AdvancedConsoleLogger],
      driver: [MysqlDriver],
      manager: [Circular *1],
      namingStrategy: [DefaultNamingStrategy],
      metadataTableName: 'typeorm_metadata',
      queryResultCache: undefined,
      relationLoader: [RelationLoader],
      relationIdLoader: [RelationIdLoader],
      isInitialized: true
    }
  },
  queryRunner: undefined
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked what _is_ being injected for `DITokens.ImageDITokens.ImageRepository` by logging out the `this.iGalleryRepository` property?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel i edited the question and pasted output to line before the last line

Comment: Looks like it doesn't have the expected methods

Comment: it just didn't extend for a reason i don't know but i solved. Thx for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Here we are, i solved.

```js
dataSource.getRepository(TypeOrmImage).extend(TypeOrmImageRepositoryAdapter)
```

supposed to work but for some reason which i really dont know it didnt. .extend wasnt working as i expected so i would dare to say that either extend is not working properly or the way i implemented was wrong. Which means if you have this error check your implementation and if it seems right then do what i did.

I just changed

```js
provide: DITokens.ImageDITokens.ImageRepository,
        useFactory: (dataSource: DataSource) => dataSource.getRepository(TypeOrmImage).extend(TypeOrmImageRepositoryAdapter),
        inject: [DITokens.CoreDITokens.DataSource]
```

> into

```js
 provide: DITokens.ImageDITokens.ImageRepository,
        useClass: TypeOrmImageRepositoryAdapter
```

and it indeed worked. Since i sue repository in the signiture of the class probably it generates typeorm repo.

Hope this helped!